# Including a WorkFlow in a WSP

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, visual-studio, feature, solution-package

I am creating a feature that I want to install a couple of workflows when activated and bind them to a list. Is there a way you can use SPD and then export your workflow to include them in your visaul studio porject? Or do you need to create the Workflows by hand in VS?

Answer (score 1):

In case you have made a 'reusable' workflow in SPD, this can be imported into visual studio and you can get started with the coding part without much difficulty.

Please follow these links as mentioned below

http://www.sjoukjezaal.com/blog/importing-sharepoint-designer-workflow-visual-studio/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231580.aspx